# How to add variables to a column in an SSIS custom component

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm very new to SSIS and have been struggling to find resources and more info on SSIS custom components. I'm working with a SSIS custom component that I have not personally written, it reads txt files and creates output columns. I was wondering if there is a way I can add new columns using the package variables I have in the SSIS package. For example, I would like to add a column that would have the filepath variable. So far all the tutorials I have seen/read have been about SSIS script component which use the read/write field that my component does not have. If I could get any help or resources that would be great, as I am very lost.

Answer (score 3):

In the Dataflow task, from the script component source, add a derived column transform to add a new column to the dataflow. In the derived column transform, utilize the variable.

[Derived Column Transformation in msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derived-column-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Is there a way I could pass the variables as parameters to my custom component and from there create new columns ? or is the derived column transform the only way ?

Comment: you can modify custom source component to add this as additional column: `IDTSOutputColumn100 column1 = output.OutputColumnCollection.New();
  IDTSExternalMetadataColumn100 exColumn1 = output.ExternalMetadataColumnCollection.New();` . you can refer to articles for custom source component. https://kzhendev.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/part-3-building-a-custom-source-component/